# Rails Customizing Devise Sign in/up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am working a new rails application, and i am adding custom values to devise. 
I added `first name`, `last name`, `username`, `phone`, and `user roles` to devise registration by doing the following:

In `app/controllers` i created `registrations_controller.rb` and added the

following:

```
   classRegistrationsController < Devise: RegistrationsController

       private

       def sign_up_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:fname, :lname, :username, :phone:, :email, :password:, :password_confirmation, :admin, :rgroup, :rlab)
       end
   end
```

And in my routes.rb i added:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations 'registrations', sessions 'sessions' }
```

Now where im stuck.

I created sessions_controller.rb in my app/controllers and in the file i have:

```
 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    private

    def sign_in_params

    end

 end
```

And what i want is to be able to sign in with username or email. But I have zero idea how to go about writing this, and most the examples online are confusing for me.

Do any of you have some tips?

Comment: You should first check the docs properly. - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos - find it, implement it and then question if you find any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all take a look at [Devise custom login](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

As an example you could do the following in your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_username

  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    # conditions[:email].downcase! if conditions[:email]
    collection = with_deleted.where(conditions.to_hash.except(:login))
    if conditions[:login]
      value = conditions[:login].downcase
      collection = collection.where("username = :value OR email = :value", value: value)
    end
    return unless record = collection.first
    record.restore(recursive: true) if record.deleted?
    record
  end

  def login
    @login || username || email
  end

  private

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

You should add the following to your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = %i(username first_name last_name phone user_role email password password_confirmation remember_me)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

Add this to your `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

And in your views (assuming your using HAML):

```
= simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :login, autofocus: true
    = f.input :password, hint: ""
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  .form-action
    = submit_tag("Login")
```